# Java static return type of method of generic class is type-erased?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

Say I have a class:

```java
public class GClass implements GInterface<Impl> {
// other code
  @Override
  public Class<SomeClass> getType() {
    return SomeClass.class
  }
}
```

That implements generic interface:

```java
public interface GInterface<T extends OtherClass> {
// other code
  Class<SomeClass> getType();
}
```

And I then call getType():

```java
GInterface gi = new GClass();
Class<SomeClass> type = gi.getType(); // <- gives warning
```

How does it make any sense that I get a warning here? The result of `getType()` is not generic (it's not using the generic type parameter T) but statically defined as `Class<SomeClass>`. Therefor the compiler should know that `Class<SomeClass> type = gi.getType()` is 100% safe right?

Am I missing something?

I expected the call: `Class<SomeClass> type = gi.getType()` to not generate any warnings.

**UPDATE**:
I now found out it has to do with the type parameter of `gi`.
This generates warning (my question is why?):

```java
GInterface gi = new GClass();
Class<SomeClass> type = gi.getType(); // <- gives warning
```

Doesnt give warning:

```java
GInterface<?> gi = new GClass();
Class<SomeClass> type = gi.getType(); // <- Doesnt give warning
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnBollinger I edited the post John. Hopefully it didn't confuse you too much!

Comment: I agree that in the code presented, the return type of `GInterface.getType()` is statically known to be `Class<SomeClass>`, not withstanding the parameterization of `GInterface`.  I see no reason for the compiler to complain.  `GClass` doesn't even factor into that particular analysis.  I'm confident that any diagnostic the compiler reports for the indicated line is related to something you haven't shown us.  This sort of thing is why we expect debugging questions to provide a MRE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GInterface gi` is a raw type. The way Java works is that raw types basically put you into a "backwards compatibility mode" within the type checker, where the type works as if it did before generics were invented (that is, it's as if you're writing Java 1.4 code). In particular, the type's method signatures are completely stripped of generics in the compile-time calculations.

That means that with `GInterface gi`, `getType()` returns a raw `Class`, not a `Class<SomeClass>`. You're then assigning that raw type to a generic type, which is where the warning comes from.

(Note that this warning really is useful: because you're converting from a raw type to a generic type, the compiler has no way of checking that the conversion is correct. `Class<FooBar> type = gi.getType()` would also compile, but wouldn't work as you expect at runtime.)

Declaring the type as `GInterface<?> gi` means it's not a raw type anymore, so `getType()`'s compile-time type is the generic'ed `Class<SomeClass>`.

Comment: Bottom line: don't use raw versions of generic types.  This has been the recommendation since Java 5, when generics were released, and the strength of that recommendation has only grown since then. (And @Bas: this is one of the reasons why it's important to be clear that your `GClass` is not generic.)

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for the extra context. My question has now been answered by this answer and your comment. :D